# Race condition even after synchronising

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to run multiple threads. I am clearly getting race condition and able to resolve it as follows:

```
final Data data = new Data();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
    final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //using this sync block to stop the race condition 
            synchronized (data){
                final int value = data.getValue();
                data.setValue(value + 1);
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

But I do not want to sync on this block and instead want to handle it at the Data class. So I removed the above sync block and instead synced the get and set methods over at the Data class as follows but this still causes race conditions. Why the issue even though I have synced them?

```
public class Data {

    private int value;

    public synchronized int getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }

    public synchronized void setValue(int num){
        this.value = num;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because without the extra synch block, multiple threads are able to call getValue() simultaneously, inc it by one, then write the same value back, even though they should have incremented by the number of times getValue() was called.

Comment: How exactly race condition manifests itself?
Also, if intention is to have thread safe increment, why don't you use [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) ?

Comment: This is a variation on double check locking (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) - as the answers indicate, you're getting and then setting separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `synchronized` to the individual methods is similar to doing something like this

```
final Data data = new Data();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
    final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (data){
                final int value = data.getValue();
            }
            synchronized (data){
                data.setValue(value + 1);
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Where a thread could very clearly get stuck between the get and the set. To resolve this, you either need to add a new synchronized method to the `Data` class that accomplishes the `value + 1` task, or wrap both lines in a `synchronized` block, as you have done in your code.

Answer (score 4):

Because you didn't. You synced either of them, so two threads cannot execute the methods at the same time, but one thread can execute `getValue()` then finishes `getValue()` and before it enters `setValue()` another thread gets its turn and calls `getValue()` which is perfectly legal and your race condition.

Btw. just in case `Data` would be your whole class, [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) would be the same, but done properly. There you e. g. have an `incrementAndGet()` method that does the read and write operation in **one** synchronisation block which is the essential point in your case.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in your `Data` class `value` should be `volatile`.

Regarding the issue you mention; You can't change the code like you did. 
Since in the way you changed it to the following can happen:

> 1) `value` in `Data` is `0`
>
> 2) `Thread 0` reads `value` (reads `0`)
>
> 3) `Thread 1` reads `value` (reads `0`)
>
> 4) `Thread 1` increments `value` and writes the new value to `Data.value` (writes `1`)
>
> 5) `Thread 0` increments `value` and writes the new value to `Data.value` (writes `1`)

The issue here is that in step 5) a `1` was written since `Thread 0` doesn't know that `Thread 1` already incremented `value` since `Thread 0` read `value`.

Comment: The use of volatile is irrelevant if multiple threads only interact with this field inside of synchronized blocks.

Comment: @KookieMonster
`volatile` has 2 functions in Java; 
1) To make sure that a partial value isn't read/written
2) To force the value to not be stored in a thread's local cache/memory
In this case you obviously don't have to worry about case 1 (technically, you never have to worry about this with `int`s)
However, unless you use `volatile` the different threads might not see the most recent value if the `int` is updated by another thread, due to in Java each thread having its own cache

Comment: In general, this is correct. But `volatile` isn't required to 'update' the values when using `synchronized`, as the values are already 'updated' at the end of a `synchronized` block (that's not to say that `volatile` and `synchronized` make the other redundant, you just don't need `volatile` in this particular situation).

Comment: @KookieMonster I'm sorry but I don't follow you, can you please explain? 
If you update a non-volatile primitive from within a synchronized block in one thread, then why would you when reading the value from another thread be guaranteed to latest value? 
Does the Java specification guarantee that before/after a `synchronized` block the "resynchronization" of memory between threads/thread caches?

Comment: Before a monitor is released, writes are flushed from thread-local memory to shared memory. In your example, and in the original question, Thread #2 will be reading the value from within synchronized block (otherwise may try to read the field before Thread #1 has even executed the write instructions), thus will see any changes which Thread #1 made while holding the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Your adding a synchronized on the method level. So one thread could be calling getValue() and one could be calling setValue(). You could remove the synchronised altogether and change the type of the private "value" member to AutomicInteger. Then utilise thread-safe method within that class.

Comment: It's not possible to synchronize on a method.  The only thing your code can ever synchronize on is an object.  A synchronized instance method synchronizes on the `this` object, and a synchronized class method synchronizes on the class object.